# in a table, in an itemize environment, how to cross-reference an equation?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, citing, lists

```
\begin{table}
\centering 
\caption{Cluster head selection}
\label{tab:algofirefly}
\vspace{.1 in} \hrule \vspace {.1 in}
Pseudo code forcluster head selection based on the firefly  is as follows: 
\vspace {.1 in} \hrule \vspace {.1 in}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Initialization 
    \item Set of sensor nodes $ \{n_1,n_2,n_3.........]\}$ is the input
    \item Each node calculate $E_{Res}^{(i)}, PL^{(i)}, dist(i,j), N_D^{(i)}
    \item All the nodes calculate the fitness function using the equation (\ref{eq:47})
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What's your question?

Comment: how to cite equation in table item

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about creating a cross-reference to an equation from within, say, a `table` environment. If there's an equation in your document with `\label{eq:whatever}`, both `(\ref{eq:whatever})` and `\eqref{eq:whatever}` (assuming you've loaded the `amsmath` package) will work well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,enumitem,amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{dist}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{46} % just for this example
\begin{equation} \label{eq:pyth} 
a^2+b^2=c^2 
\end{equation}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Cluster head selection\strut}
\label{tab:algofirefly}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X @{}}
\toprule
Pseudo code for cluster head selection based on the firefly is as follows:\\ 
\midrule
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[left=0pt]
    \item Initialization 
    \item Set of sensor nodes $ \{n_1,n_2,n_3,\dots\}$ is the input.
    \item Each node calculates $E_{\mathrm{Res}}^{(i)}$, $\mathit{PL}^{(i)}$, $\dist(i,j)$, and $N_{\!D}^{(i)}$.
    \item All nodes calculate the fitness function using equation \eqref{eq:pyth}.
\end{itemize} 
\end{minipage} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you will do that